# Estou com o seguinte erro no VBA "erro em tempo de execução 13 tipos incompatíveis"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, outlook

Estou criando um código para enviar e-mail automaticamente, porém meu código trava com este erro no `Email.Body`:

> erro em tempo de execução 13 tipos incompatíveis

Estou fazendo algo errado?

```
Set objeto = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Email = objeto.createitem(0)

    Email.Display
    Email.to = Cells(2, 6).Value
    Email.cc = Cells(2, 7).Value
    Email.Subject = Cells(2, 3).Value & Cells(9, 6).Value
    **Email.Body** = "Olá, boa tarde!" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Cells(2, 2).Value _
    & Cells(2, 8).Value & Cells(9, 6).Value & "." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Temos o total de" & "" & Cells(2, 5).Value _
    & "" & "remessas pendentes." & Chr(10) & Chr(10)

    Email.Send
```

Comment: Ao pedir ajuda sobre um erro, é útil sempre informar a linha do erro. Além disso, no seu caso, você não colocou no código a declaração das variáveis (que é essencial para saber o tipo esperado pelo VBA, cuja desconformidade é a razão do erro "tipos incompatíveis").

Answer (score 0):

Eu testei seu código declarando as variáveis **objeto** e **Email** como **Variant** e funcionou normal no meu computador.

### Declaração das variáveis como **Variant**:

> ```
> Dim objeto As Variant
> Dim Email As Variant
> ```

Talvez você tenha definido suas variáveis como de outro tipo e isso tenha causado o problema.

Mas, se o problema persistir, nos informe o seu código completo e em qual linha especificamente ocorre o erro.

### O código completo ficou assim:

```
Sub GerarEmail()

    Dim objeto As Variant
    Dim Email As Variant
    
    Set objeto = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = objeto.createitem(0)
    
    Email.Display
    Email.to = Cells(2, 6).Value
    Email.cc = Cells(2, 7).Value
    Email.Subject = Cells(2, 3).Value & Cells(9, 6).Value
    Email.Body = "Olá, boa tarde!" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Cells(2, 2).Value _
        & Cells(2, 8).Value & Cells(9, 6).Value & "." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Temos o total de " & "" & Cells(2, 5).Value _
        & "" & "remessas pendentes." & Chr(10) & Chr(10)

End Sub
```